# creating autocomplete in android

Tags: android

I want to create a AutoCompleteTextView in android. The problem is that I want to show whole list of data when user selects AutoCompleteTextView and start filtering data as user types the letters.Please help me in doing this.

Comment: please update you code & if you got an error then also update logcate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here is an way how you can do that,

declare an String array -

`String[] array = new String[]{"first","second","third","fourth"};`

Now, initialize the Adapter with the source.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,array);
```

Finally fetch the AutoCompleteTextView id from your xml and set the adapter.

```
AutoCompleteTextView mView = (AutoCompleteTextView) 
                                             findViewById(R.id.myAutoTextView);
mView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This works fine but my problem is different.I want to show all the value in String array when user selects the AutoCompleteText and the data should get filtered when user starts typing.

Comment: Well, this should do that only try it. It will filter the values automatically....

Comment: Yes,it is filtering the data but it is not listing all the values inside String array when I am just clicking on AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: I want all the values of String array to be displayed when I just click on AutoCompleteTextView and filtering when start typing.